# Rename folder in Git. All branches and all revisions

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I'm facing issue while checking out a branch in windows. One folder ends with an empty space in it, causing windows to automatically trim the folder, while git is trying to put files in original path and causing an error.

```
fatal: cannot create directory at 'raisesoft/61571_delivery /acl': No such file or directory
```

On linux it works fine as linux doesn't trim the folders automatically.

I'm trying to rename that folder. This is the script I came up with:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter '
if [ -d "61571_delivery " ]; then
  mv "61571_delivery " "61571_delivery"
fi' --force HEAD
```

However it doesn't work. It didn't rename the folder at all. I'm not proficient in linux bash, so little help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if it works fine on linux, why don't you try pushing a commit after renaming the directory manually on linux?

Comment: The command as written would look for the directory at the repo root.  I got the impression from the error message that it's really in a subdirectory of the repo; do you just need to qualify the path in your script?

Comment: A couple other notes: you probably want to add `-- --all` to the end of the `filter-branch` arguments (since you said all revisions).  If the repo is very big, this should take considerable time (since it must fully check out, update, and re-commit every existing version).  And in case you haven't yet planned for this: the operation will change the SHA1 ID of every commit, requiring a cut-over procedure for any/all users of this repo.

Comment: @ashmaroli because I want to be able to checkout all revisions on windows. Your solution would work only for future revisions.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger yes, but I coulnd't manage to make it work for a single branch yet, I will run -- all when I have a workign solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically on the right track.  Your tree filter is just looking for the wrong name.  The path name of the directory is not:

```
"61571_delivery "
```

(complete with trailing space that needs a quote mark to make it clear), but rather:

```
"raisesoft/61571_delivery "
```

Hence:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter '
if [ -d "61571_delivery " ]; then
  mv "61571_delivery " "61571_delivery"
fi' --force HEAD
```

should read:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter '
if [ -d "raisesoft/61571_delivery " ]; then
  mv "raisesoft/61571_delivery " "raisesoft/61571_delivery"
fi' --force HEAD
```

(and once you test it and see that it works, switch to `--all` and add `--tag-name-filter cat` to get annotated tags changed as well).

It's worth noting that `--tree-filter` is *extremely* slow.  On a large repository, doing this on spinning media (rather than SSD or memory file system) can take days or even weeks.  You can speed it up a lot by using a memory file system, but your biggest speedup comes from using an `--index-filter` rather than a `--tree-filter`.  With a tree filter, Git must extract each commit from the index into a regular file system tree, run your filter, then convert the tree back into an index it can use to write a new commit.  While no part of `git filter-branch` is *fast*, this is the slowest part.  With an index filter, Git gets to skip this step entirely: it just reads the commit into the index, runs your index filter, then writes a new commit from the index.

Unfortunately, there's no good out-of-the-box way to write an index filter that does this.  You basically want the Git equivalent of `hg mv --after` to rename files in the index only—but Git doesn't have it.  I wrote [a script that does this for one file](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-mv-after), but you want to do it for every file within a directory.

Comment: Huh. I’m surprised there’s no `git mv --cached`.

Comment: @DanielH: there *should* be!